# ViewController gets completely messed up , screenshots attached

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller

I have an application where i use a controller which has multiple fields to write something inside with a keyboard or with a picker. I also have a button that when you hit it you navigate to another controller to take a picture and when you are done you return to the previous controller. If i try to fill the fields before i visit the "camera" controller everything looks good like the picture below :

[image]

However if i press the camera button navigate to the "camera controller" and the return to this controller to fill the fields when i tap a field the picker gets completely messed up and appears like this :

[image]

Any ideas why this is happening? I cant understand what i changes in my code and cause this as some versions before it was working fine...

Comment: posting some of that code would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the picker is going into landscape mode and not registering the change back to portrait later on. Are you making sure to destroy the picker when you're done with it?

Answer (score 0):

you DiffMerge to find what changes you made between two versions (if you want to see all diffs between two folders).

Also, it looks like your view frames are either getting messed up or you are showing the picker wrong.

If you camera view is doing something in landscape mode or status bar goes landscape, on dismissing it, you may see the frame values messed up. Just print/nslog the frame width every time you show this picker. you'll be able to figure out where its going wrong.